# Explain attribute selection for arcpy.SpatialJoin_analysis

Tags: arcpy, spatial-join

I have exported a ModelBuilder model to python script, but it is failing.  I suspect it is the attribute selection that is the problem.  This model does a series of Spatial Join tasks one after the other (5 in total).

I have created a simple script that does a single Spatial Join to use as a test.  This works successfully, but I do not understand what the various inputs mean.

Can anyone explain what the options are that I don't understand.

```
# Import arcpy module
import arcpy

# Script arguments
Property_SpatialJoin2 = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)
if Property_SpatialJoin2 == '#' or not Property_SpatialJoin2:
  Property_SpatialJoin2 = "filepath\\Property_SpatialJoin2" # provide a default value if unspecified

# Local variables:
Property_shp = "filepath\\Property.shp"
MM_EIL_shp = "filepath\\MM_EIL.shp"

# Process: Spatial Join
arcpy.SpatialJoin_analysis(Property_shp, MM_EIL_shp, Property_SpatialJoin2, "JOIN_ONE_TO_ONE", "KEEP_ALL", "HAS_Code \"HAS_Code\" true true false 30 Text 0 0 ,First,#,filepath\\Property.shp,HAS_Code,-1,-1;Contact \"Contact\" true true false 50 Text 0 0 ,First,#,filepath\\Property.shp,Contact,-1,-1;EIL_vers \"EIL_vers\" true true false 10 Long 0 10 ,First,#,filepath\\MM_EIL.shp,EIL_vers,-1,-1", "INTERSECT", "", "")
```

The section that I do not understand is what the options are for the attributes to include:

```
HAS_Code \"HAS_Code\" true true false 30 Text 0 0 ,First,#,filepath\\Property.shp,HAS_Code,-1,-1
```

The sections I (think I) know are:
 `First` refers to the join match, and can also be Min/Sum/Mean etc.
 `HAS_Code \"HAS_Code\"` gives the name of the attribute as it is called in the existing layer followed by what will be used in the new layer
 `filepath\\Property.shp,HAS_Code` gives the path to the file that has the attribute

I am not sure what the `true true false 30 Text 0 0` refers to
or what the `#` and `-1,-1` do.

Comment: That's a field mapping object http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//018z00000078000000 they're optional.. I usually skip them unless there's something specific I'm after.

Comment: I'm trying to understand what they actually do - I've read the help but don't understand it.  If I delete the true true false 30 Text 0 0 it fails - so at least part of it is doing something essential, but I don't know what.  I need to figure out how to get a more complicated problem working, but don't even understand the most basic.

Comment: Posting the error may help.

Comment: @ShadowLearn - the code I am running works, but I don't understand it, which is limiting me from using the options effectively.

Comment: A fieldmap object helps in merge/join/overlay operations by allowing the user to control what the joined field is called, or even if a field is used at all, for example if I had two datasets with an important attribute that had the same name in both I could use a fieldmap object to force one of the fields into a new name, and let's say I had some fields that I didn't care about, with the fieldmap object I can specify not to have them in the output at all.. like I said, they're optional, so I usually don't work with them *unless* there is a specific need as I see it as an unneeded complication.